# Hangout crashing

Tags: stock-android, google-hangouts, 7.0-nougat

I run the Android N Developer Preview 4 on my Sony Xperia Z3. Works fantastic only Hangout crashes when I wrote anything.

Then when I can wrote it must wait ~15 seconds then the message is showing up. Anyone with the same issue?

Comment: I have the same issue with a stock Nexus 6.